# What is wrong with "Check my Latin" questions?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, specific-question, closed-questions

What is wrong with questions asking for a proof-reading of a short text written in Latin, such as [my question on a joke about mathematics which got closed](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/17829/check-my-latin-a-joke-about-mathematics)?

Comment: You seem to have edited that question to add an English original. That's good, and it has generated some votes to reopen. How about addressing the other questions in my answer below? I will not oppose to others reopening it now, but I will not do so myself unless the questions (which were also given in comments to one of the questions in that series) are addressed more broadly. If you are asking to check whether your translation is good, you probably have a reason to doubt yourself. What is that reason? What would you like feedback on? I was not joking when I asked you to answer all questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem with that question is that it contains no question.
Are you worried about some specific aspect of your translation?
Do you want it to be classical or contemporary?
What is the English original text?
Are you interested in style, grammar, vocabulary, or something else?
What would a good answer give you?
Where, if anywhere, do you plan to use the translation?
If there are technical terms or jokes that won't be clear to everyone, can you explain them?

I closed that question and two others at the same time, leaving a comment only under [one of them](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/17827/79):

> I closed this question and the other similar unanswered one and the answered one for lack of details. See the comments above for details; they apply to all questions. Please edit to elaborate so that your question contains a clear question and goal!

The other comments to that question are worth taking seriously, too.
All the comments and the closure banner saying "Add details and clarify the problem being solved." are a pretty clear pointer.

Asking for feedback on a translation of your own is on topic.
It just needs to contain a specific question.
My suggestion is to edit the question so that it contains an answer to **all** (yes, all) of the questions in my opening paragraph here.